# Connecting Environment with database on AWS

Tags: database, amazon-web-services

I'm very new to Amazon Web Services and I'm trying to deploy and run Wordpress site that in on my localhost. Currently I don't have access to the SSH and everything I do from the Web management dashboard of AWS.

So, I've created one instance and Uploaded/Deployed the zip with the site. Then I created database RDS with table name `myTable`, and connected to it via Dbeaver tool. Then I've included my database sql file to create tables etc.

Database credentials(changed for the question):

1) username: Master
2) password: MasterPassword

In the `wp-config.php` I've added

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'myTable');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'Master');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'MasterPassword');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

When I go to the URL that elastic Beanstalk gave me I see the error:

> Error establishing a database connection

Which obvious means that the site can't connect to database. My question is if there is something that I miss and just adding the credentials in `wp_config.php` isn't enought

Comment: `localhost` is obviously not the correct DB_HOST address. You need to use the hostname of the RDS instance. You will probably also need to configure the security group of the RDS instance to allow incoming traffic from your Elastic Beanstalk environment.

Comment: Oh, I tough that the instance is on the same server(?) like the database and it is same like on my localhost

Comment: In this case my DB_HOST would be the Endpoint, right?

Comment: Yes it would be the RDS Endpoint. RDS is a separate server from the EC2 server managed by your Elastic Beanstalk environment. Honestly I see this as a very over complicated and expensive way to run a Wordpress site. Have you looked at Amazon Lightsail, or Digital Ocean?

Comment: No, I didn't saw Amazon Lightsail yet. I will. One more question about the allowing incoming traffic to database. I don't see where/how I can add the IP of my EC2. Where I can add it?

Comment: Well first you don't want to use the IP of the EC2 instance because it is subject to change. You want to edit the Security Group of the RDS instance and allow incoming traffic to everything belonging to the Security Group that the EC2 instance belongs to.

Comment: Or in other word in INBOUND of the RDS `TCP`  and for the SOURCE I need to add the security group that has the EC2?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Thank you @MarkB, I've made changes to the wp-config.php and currently re-uploading the zip file. Once I tried it will let you know

Comment: Thanks @MarkB, now seems that it is working correctly.